# Docker does not recognize 64bit kernel

Tags: docker, arm, arm64

I run my Raspberry Pi4 in 64 bit mode as you can see here:

> $ uname -a 
> Linux jan-raspberry4 5.10.17-v8+ #1421 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 27 14:01:37 BST 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux

When I try to pull an image which is for 64 bit available only, I receive this message:

> $ docker pull gitlab/gitlab-runner
> Using default tag: latest 
> latest: Pulling from gitlab/gitlab-runner 
> no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Could you run `file /bin/ls`?

Comment: > /bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=67a394390830ea3ab4e83b5811c66fea9784ee69, stripped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel is 64-bit, but your userland is not.

In 2020, [Raspberry Pi OS launched a 64-bit beta](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=275370) and as far as I can tell, at the time of writing they are still in beta with known issues. The 64-bit builds can be downloaded from here:
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/

If you're not comfortable running beta software, [Ubuntu has stable 64-bit builds for the Raspberry Pi](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi), as do [a bunch of other Linux flavours](https://linuxhint.com/5-best-linux-distributions-for-raspberry-pi-compared/).